# vuejs child component lifecycle diffrence root component?

Tags: vue.js

this is my template

```
<parent>
 <child></child>
</parent>
```

and this is child component script

```
beforeCreate(){
    console.log('beforeCreate');
}

created(){
    console.log('created');
}

beforeMount(){
    console.log('beforeMount');
}
```

i test vuejs component lifecycle.

so i write all hook method in child component,

but created hook method in child is not called

is it normal or not??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should work normally as other lifecycle methods. I've retested your case (based on vue cli webpack template) and it's working fine. Are you using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) or custom bundle / build way?

Please, see my example below (I guess you miss comma after lifecycle method curly bracket):

```
<script>
  // PARENT component
  import Child from './components/Child'

  export default {
    name: 'parent',

    components: {
     Child
    }
 }
</script>


<script>
  // CHILD component
  export default {
    name: 'child',

    beforeMount () {
     console.log('before mount')
    },

    created () {
      console.log('created')
    },
    beforeCreate () {
      console.log('before create')
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: i use vue class (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) . if your code work well, then it is vue class problem.. thanks